# Grails quartz plugin is not working when deployed in Tomcat

Tags: grails, tomcat6, quartz-scheduler, war

I have a web application that was developed using Grails. I'm trying to implement a background process that scans a table in DB for every 5 mins using quartz1.0-RC9 plugin for Grails.

Before trying to code the actual logic I'm learning how to use the plugin as I'm new to quartz. So I created a job that prints the message "hai" with the current timestamp for every 5 seconds.

```
class checkJob {
    static triggers = {
      simple name:'sampleQuartz', startDelay:10000, repeatInterval: 5000l, repeatCount: -1 // execute job once in 5 seconds
    }

    def execute() {
        println "hai!!!"+new Date()// execute job
    }
}
```

And my QuartzConfig.groovy is

```
quartz {
    autoStartup = true
    jdbcStore = false
    waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown = true
    exposeSchedulerInRepository = false

    props {
        scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true
    }
}

environments {
    test {
        quartz {
            autoStartup = true
        }
    }
    production {
        quartz {
            autoStartup = true
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine when run using the command `grails run-app`. But when a war is created using the command `grails prod war` and when deployed in Tomcat nothing works. Even the index.html page is not loading instead it gives Http-404 error.

I have referenced this plugin in BuilConfig.groovy as mentioned in the documentation under plugin category.

```
compile ":quartz:1.0-RC9"
```

But yet nothing works.

Then I created a new Grails project that has nothing but only the quartz code mentioned above and created a war using `grails prod war`. This works fine with Tomcat.

I'm using

> Tomcat 6
>  Grails 2.0.1
>  quartz 1.0-RC9

What I'm missing while creating a job in already existing grails application?

Please somebody help me.

I did some groundwork on this issue. On creating war of my grails application "Timeprocess" by `grails dev-war` and deploying under Tomcat6, I am getting the following in localhost.txt file

```
Jul 29, 2013 3:35:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jul 29, 2013 3:35:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class grails.plugins.quartz.DefaultGrailsJobClass
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:905)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:740)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class grails.plugins.quartz.DefaultGrailsJobClass
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ArtefactHandlerAdapter.newArtefactClass(ArtefactHandlerAdapter.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.addArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:894)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.addArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:615)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.configureLoadedClasses(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:326)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.initialise(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:825)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ArtefactHandlerAdapter.newArtefactClass(ArtefactHandlerAdapter.java:104)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
    at grails.plugins.quartz.config.TriggersConfigBuilder.createTrigger(TriggersConfigBuilder.groovy:74)
    at grails.plugins.quartz.config.TriggersConfigBuilder.createNode(TriggersConfigBuilder.groovy:215)
    at grails.plugins.quartz.config.TriggersConfigBuilder.createNode(TriggersConfigBuilder.groovy:208)
    at Timeprocess.ScheduleScanJob$__clinit__closure1.doCall(ScheduleScanJob.groovy:7)
    at grails.plugins.quartz.config.TriggersConfigBuilder.build(TriggersConfigBuilder.groovy:52)
    at grails.plugins.quartz.DefaultGrailsJobClass.evaluateTriggers(DefaultGrailsJobClass.java:58)
    at grails.plugins.quartz.DefaultGrailsJobClass.<init>(DefaultGrailsJobClass.java:48)
Jul 29, 2013 3:35:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Jul 29, 2013 3:35:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Jul 29, 2013 3:36:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
Jul 29, 2013 3:36:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
```

Can anyone please help me to point-out what's is wrong in here?

Comment: The same quartz code works in fresh application but not in old one so probably the problem is with your application and not the quartz code

Try "grails prod run-war" with old application and see if problem reproduces.

Comment: I tried as you mentioned @sudhir . But nothing came in tomcat-out.txt under target. Only "Server running. Browse to 8080:8080localhost"

Comment: Please... Someone help me out in this as I'm struggling...!

Comment: @VasanthRajasekaran: I see the error "Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
" in your log. Maybe you have two versions of the same library loaded in your Tomcat.

Comment: IncompatibleClassChangeError is often caused by conflicts in loading libraries (accidentally pull 2 versions of the same library as dependency, or using the incompatible version of library). I would recommend you try a grails clean, and if it doesn't get resolved, try removing the current Quartz library in the repository

Comment: I tried grails clean and deployed war in tomcat but with no luck. If I have to remove Quartz library means where I have to remove? I don't see any library files belonging to Quartz under lib folder.

Comment: @VasanthRajasekaran: I remember that the libraries used for Grails will reside in the hidden .grails folder in your user home folder. Please give it a check

Comment: Have you tried running "grails dependency-report" to see if there are any conflicting quartz dependencies that are being pulled in from somewhere?

Comment: Have you tried using the actual 1.0.1 release version of Quartz? I'm curious why you are using 1.0-RC9. I recall at one point some incompatibilities with Quartz2 and Spring 3 (early on) and also a bug in simple triggers with a few versions.

Comment: @VasanthRajasekaran is  your jdk version is different in your server system

Comment: @VasanthRajasekaran have you fixed this already?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest doing a:

```
grails clean
```

and also deleting the .slcache folder, that you can find under

```
~/.grails/.slcache
```

regards