# Background process plugin for grails

Tags: grails, process, background

I have a Grails application in which I want a thread to run in background as soon as my application starts that queries the database and gets the resultset. This operation should happen for every 5 mins.

I have searched and found that quartz plugin for grails is a best one but that plugin works in Grails run-app but not when deployed as a war in Tomcat.

Is there any other plugin other than quartz for doing this operation?

Please give some suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Bootstrap.groovy** to run code when application starts. Just place code you want to `def init = { servletContext ->}` section.
Use  `YourJob.triggerNow()` to force job run on application start.

Comment: In Bootstrap.groovy itself can we provide a timer to run the job recursively for every 5 min?

Comment: No, you can just force to run in Bootstrap.groovy. After app started let quartz do his job. See http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/guide/scheduling.html to learn more how to configure jobs

Comment: Actually the problem is, quartz is not working when deployed as a war in Tomcat. So how can I start the thread and have it recursively?

Comment: Can you give me any example? Because when I try to give def invokeTrigger = MyJob.triggerNow() nothing happens. Infact grails run-app itself is not working.

Comment: Are you sure that nothing happens? Add some logs to job. If you can't run app look for any exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

> I have searched and found that quartz plugin for grails is a best one
>   but that plugin works in Grails run-app but not when deployed as a war
>   in Tomcat.

I don't think it's true. [Quartz](http://grails.org/plugin/quartz) plugin should work in production environment as well as in development mode. I used them in some projects.

Comment: FYI please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832586/grails-quartz-plugin-is-not-working-when-deployed-in-tomcat?noredirect=1#comment26028184_17832586) post.

Comment: @VasanthRajasekaran: I have replied to your original question. Looks like you have a library problem, please have a check.

Comment: Is there anything else other than quartz to perform this task in Grails

Comment: first, quartz is very popular and well-supported with Grails. Of course you can integrate with other Java libraries, just not as easy. Here's the list: http://java-source.net/open-source/job-schedulers

Comment: Just a note: the conflicting libraries may trouble you another time (since this is not the specific problem with Quartz), so I would recommend you solve it the earlier the better